# Google Chrome showing error if I have folder name as "Support"

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome is showing error "The site ahead contains harmful programs" if I try to open any page which is in Support folder. eg: http://www.investarindia.com/Support/Default.aspx

Now when I changed folder name from "Support" to "Support1" all the pages started working. Here I have question that what is the issue with folder name "Support"? Any folder name is working in IE and firefox. I am not in state to change folder name as it is used at multiple places outside the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some malware (specifically, some kind of virus) being distributed under that Support folder. Google has a [page explaining how to get your site removed from the blacklist](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/163633?rd=1). You should also check out the [diagnostic page](https://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.investarindia.com%2FSupport%2FDefault.aspx&client=googlechrome&hl=en-US) linked from the 'Details' page on the alert.

Comment: So does it mean that once chrome encounters some malicious thing it makes a note that the page contains "harmful program" and then even if I remove that suspected downloading link, it will not check for the link present or not and directly displays error.

Comment: Read the first link; it'll give you instructions on how to get google to re-scan your site and remove it from the blacklist. This will also affect google search results pointing to your site, note.